# python - subprocess - Open terminal with a file

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to make an automated script which should run a set of commands in the same Terminal Window (Mac OS X Yosemite). But I could not reach the stage where I can continue adding the commands.

**Automator.py**

```
path = '/Users/aakashshah/documents/python/test.py'

def subprocess_cmd(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    proc_stdout = process.communicate()[0].strip()
    print(proc_stdout)

subprocess_cmd('cd /Users/aakashshah/documents/python/ | open -a Terminal | python test.py')
```

Result is that the Terminal application opens with just the root name.

The similar command runs in the terminal with desired output in the same terminal window.

Thankyou. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the `|`s supposed to mean? Do you want to build a Unix pipe from  `cd`, `open`, `python`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe using Popen and use cwd:

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE


def subprocess_cmd(dr,cmd1,cmd2):
    p1 = Popen(cmd1.split(),stdout=PIPE,cwd=dr)
    p2 = Popen(cmd2.split(),stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=PIPE,cwd=dr)
    p1.stdout.close()
    return p2.communicate()[0]

subprocess_cmd('/Users/aakashshah/documents/python/','open -a Terminal','python test.py')
```

If you just want to run the python file the first cmd1 is unnecessary.

Comment: Still shows the same result. The Terminal window opens empty.

Comment: why are you opening a Terminal?

Comment: Well yes you are right. I was focusing more on the look and feel. I want to open an ftp connection basically and unzip a file. Ill figure that out. Thanks.

Comment: pexpect might be what you want https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/blob/master/examples/ftp.py